# Total sum within loop

Tags: templating, forloop, group, math

I have simple loop:

```
{% for total in thing %}
  {{ total.seatsKids }} {{ total.seatsParents }}
{% endfor %}
```

This results in a string of numbers eg. `1 3 4`. I want the sum of all numbers. So how do I get `8` at the end? I don't understand how to write math operations within loops.

Comment: Where does the "1" come from? Did you mean "3 4"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do math in twig, you will need to use the [set](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html) tag to do assignments, and the [+](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math) operator to do addition. When doing math inside a [for](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) loop, you will need to keep in mind that

> loops are scoped in Twig; therefore a variable declared inside a for loop is not accessible outside the loop itself.
>   If you want to access the variable, just declare it before the loop.

It looks as if you have a collection of things that represent seat counts, and you want to loop over them and calculate the totals. So, something like this:

```
{# define and intialize our variables outside the loop #}
{% set kidSeatTotal = 0 %}
{% set parentSeatTotal = 0 %}

{# loop over the seatCounts and add them up #}
{% for seatCount in thing %}
  {% set kidSeatTotal = kidSeatTotal + seatCount.seatsKids %}
  {% set parentSeatTotal = parentSeatTotal + seatCount.seatsParents %}
{% endfor %}

{# maybe we want the grand total as well #}
{% set grandSeatTotal = kidSeatTotal + parentSeatTotal %}

{# now we can output them: #}
kid seat total: {{ kidSeatTotal }}
parent seat total: {{ parentSeatTotal }}
grand total: {{ grandSeatTotal }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some twig math, found at the bottom of the page here:

[Twig Templating](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html)

Not sure without seeing the rest of your code, but you could do something like this:

```
{% set totals = [3,4]%}
{% for total in totals %}
  {{ total }}
  {% set sum = total + sum ?? 0 %}
  {% if loop.last %}{{ sum }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Should output 34 and lastly 7**

Or more specifically to your code, roughly (not tested)

```
{% for total in thing %}
  {{ total.seatsKids }} {{ total.seatsParents }}
  {% set sum = total.seatKids + total.seatsParents + sum ?? 0 %}
  {% if loop.last %}{{ sum }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Should output 123456 and lastly 21**

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a simpler solution, current versions of Twig provide some filters borrowed from the functional programming paradigm to make operations like this easier: [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html), [map](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/map.html) and [reduce](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/reduce.html). With those methods, operations like this can be done in one line, reducing noise in your code and eliminating some common sources for bugs (like off-by-one errors).

Some examples for this specific requirement:

```twig
{% set seatCounts = [
    { seatsKids: 5, seatsParents: 7, },
    { seatsKids: 6, seatsParents: 3, },
    { seatsKids: 0, seatsParents: 4, },
] %}

{% set totalSeatsKids = seatCounts|reduce((carry, current) => carry + current.seatsKids, 0) %}
{% set totalSeatsParents = seatCounts|reduce((carry, current) => carry + current.seatsParents, 0) %}

{% set totalSeatsAll = seatCounts
    |map(current => current.seatsKids + current.seatsParents)
    |reduce((carry, current) => carry + current)
%}

totalSeatsKids: {{ totalSeatsKids }} <br>
totalSeatsParents: {{ totalSeatsParents }} <br>
totalSeatsAll: {{ totalSeatsAll }} <br>
```